# Типы элементов в Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

Где можно увидеть все доступные типы, которые используются в Angular?

Я имею в виду 
 - HTMLInputElement, HTMLFormElement, ElementRef, KeyboardEvent, FormControl, SimpleChanges и др.

Есть какой-нибудь один общий список? Спасибо!

Comment: зачем это тебе нужно?

Comment: Для общего понимания всей картины и хочу по максимуму использовать типизацию в коде

Comment: смотри исходный код и учи angular, тогда будешь знать какие типы он экспортит, по-другому никак :)

Comment: Я так и делаю), просто подумала, что где-нибудь есть общий список) Было бы проще и понятнее)

Comment: есть открытое апи у них в документации, поищи, мне лень просто искать :D

Comment: Поняла, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

это стандартные Интерфейсы веб API
смотреть например здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API